# how can I handle proper highcharts resizes with angular flex layout

Tags: angular, highcharts, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I have the problem when I put a highcharts chart into a flex container created with angular flex layout it does have some height issues when it comes to changing the screen size.

The layout is pretty basic there is a header footer and a content area. When the app loads up everything looks fine and the width gets adjusts well on changes. But when increase the height and decrease again it does not scale back. I think it has something todo with my flexboxes but I really don't understand why. With the devtools activated I see that the highcharts container stays the same size.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-angular-flex-layout-holy-grail-design-8wdp4k?file=src/app/footer/footer.component.html

Comment: Have you tried reflow? https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#reflow

Comment: in this example if the chart grows none of the events (window or div) fire since their dimension are not changing anymore. So there is no hook calling reflow when you resize the window. Both window and others do not fire. If I remove the chart all of the events do fire. I'm really confused and I don't know whats happening

Comment: I suspect that the source of this issue lays in the `angular/-flex-layout`. Because after I simplified that layout, the chart resizes correctly. Please check the  `home.component.html` file https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-angular-flex-layout-holy-grail-design-sf9kdf

Comment: yeah I suspect that as well. But on your changes the height of the component does not shrink back. Then its the same behavior as before...I'll try to make a new reproducer without angular flex